# Count the identical string elements in Ruby array

Tags: ruby, arrays, count

I can't find a simple solution for this problem

For example we have an array:

```
["a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "a", "a", "a"]
```

I need to count the identical elements in this way:

```
[["a", 5], ["b", 2], ["c", 1], ["a", 3]]
```

Comment: That is not a valid Ruby code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uses the [`chunk`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) method to group identical elements, then uses `map` to convert `[letter, array]` pairs to `[letter, count]`.

```
arr     = ["a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "a", "a", "a"]
counted = arr.chunk { |x| x }.map { |a, b| [a, b.count] } 
# => [["a", 5], ["b", 2], ["c", 1], ["a", 3]]
```

Comment: Thanks, it fixed a similar problem I have, which I need sort it first. `counted = arr.sort.chunk { |x| x }.map { |a, b| [a, b.count] }`

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby 2.2 you could use [Enumable#slice_when](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when):

```
arr = ["a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "a", "a", "a"]

arr.slice_when { |e,f| e!=f }.map { |a| [a.first, a.size] }
  #=> [["a", 5], ["b", 2], ["c", 1], ["a", 3]]
```

Comment: oh,2.2 version have a new method #slice_when.

Comment: @user3673267, also [Enumerable#slice_after](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_after).